# Best way to store configuration in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a scenario where i need to store configurations in mysql table having three columns namely **VendorID**,**ServiceID** and **ModeID** . Configuration for a vendor can be done with three overriding cases as follows.

1. One column VendorID having non-NULL value with ServiceID ,ModeID having NULL value.

VendorID,ServiceID,ModeID -- >  1,NULL,NULL

2. Two columns VendorID,ServiceID having non-NULL values with ModeID having NULL value.

VendorID,ServiceID,ModeID -- >  1,1,NULL

3. All three columns having non NULL values.

VendorID,ServiceID,ModeID -- >  1,1,1

When case 1,2,3 are defined and in the MySQL query WHERE clause vendorid,servideid and modeid are passed, then case 3 overrides case 2 and case 1.

When case 3 is not defined and case 1,2 are defined and  in the MySQL query WHERE clause vendorid,servideid and modeid are passed, then case 2 overrides case 1.

When case 3 and case 2 are not defined and case 1 is defined and  in the MySQL query WHERE clause vendorid,servideid and modeid are passed, then case 1 is returned.

Now my question is, how can i query the table to get the configuration returned when vendorid,servideid and modeid are passed in the query in one go without having to query 3 times separately.

Any other good approach for the above problem is also welcome.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: You said it yourself in post already more or less by using the word case all the time but you can use CASE END flowcontrol in SQL.. If you want better help you could provide a [example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You may want this:

```
where (VendorID, ServiceID, ModelID) = ($VendorID, $ServiceID, $ModelID) or
      ( (VendorID, ServiceID) = ($VendorID, $ServiceID) and ModelId is null) or
      ( VendorID = $VendorID and ServiceID is null and ModelId is null)
```

Alternatively you may want:

```
select t.*
from t
where VendorId = $VendorId and
      (ServiceId = $ServiceId or ServiceId is null) and
      (ModelId = $ModelId or ModelId is null)
order by ( ServiceId is not null ) desc,
         ( ModelId is not null ) desc
limit 1;
```

This returns one row with the best match.